# Show that there is $f_{0} \in \overline{\mathcal{F}}$ \such that $J(f_{0}) = \min_{f \in \overline{\mathcal{F}}}J(f)$

Tags: real-analysis, arzela-ascoli

> Let $\mathcal{F} \subset C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ be a family of functions such that:
>
> - $f'(x)$ exist for every $x \in (0,1)$, $\forall f \in \mathcal{F}$;
> - $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}}|f(0)| < \infty$;
> - $M = \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}}\sup_{x \in (0,1)} |f'(x)| < \infty$.
>
> Let $J:= C([0,1],\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ the functional defined by
> $$J(f) = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1 + f(x)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x.$$
> Show that there is $f_{0} \in \overline{\mathcal{F}}$ such that $J(f_{0}) = \min_{f \in \overline{\mathcal{F}}}J(f)$, where $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ denotes the closure of $\mathcal{F}$ relatively the norm of supremum.

My idea is to apply Ascoli-Arzelà to $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ so, $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ is compact and $J$ restrict to $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ has a minimum. For this, I need to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous and equibounded. This is my problem.

*Equicontinuity.* Given $\epsilon > 0$, $|f'|$ is bounded, by the MVTheorem, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M|x-y|$. So, taking $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$ we conclude the result. Is correct?

*Equibounded.* I didn't get anything.

---

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uniform boundedness, use $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(y) dy$, then use your second and third hypotheses and the triangle inequality.

Comment: $|f(x)| \leq |f(0)| + \left|\int_{0}^{x}f'(y)\mathrm{d}y\right| \leq |f(0)| + \int_{0}^{1}M\mathrm{d}y = |f(0)| + M$, right?

Comment: @LucasCorrêa Yep.

Comment: Great! Thank you!